# LAMP server hosting multiple domains - how to ensure each domain's files and users locked to only that domain?

Tags: php, lamp

I have a LAMP server (Ubuntu) running PHP. I want to host multiple domains on it.

My plan is to create different user for each domain because I want to make sure if one domain gets hacked, it wont affect other domains.

My worry is if one domain gets hacked, how do I prevent hacker from uploading a rogue PHP file that can grab data from my other domains? Is there a way to restrict all PHP files in a certain domain to only operate within that directory and not outside it?

Comment: Hosting a true separated, secure multiple-domain environment is a bit of a project. I think the scope of this question may be a bit broad.

Comment: This is related somewhat  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1573038 as is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424384/prevent-php-from-including-accessing-files-in-lower-directory  and finally http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=301055.0

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to do this. SELinux being one. Virtual servers being another. If you're really savvy, perhaps LXC containers.

But your provided question is far too broad to provide a detailed answer. I'd suggest doing some researching and then ask us specifics if you run into problems testing out potential solutions.